# Leer variable caracter por caracter

Tags: c++, c++11

Necesito hacer un programa en el que ingreses un número y vea si dentro de ese número hay un número definido y según ese número de un resultado distinto

Por ejemplo tengo que buscar si al principio de un número `x` están los dígitos 3 y 7 en ese orden:

> Input: 3792
>
> Output: Verdadero
>
> Input: 9264
>
> Output: Falso

O que si en ese mismo dígito `x`, en el final de este aparecen los número 8 y 2 en ese orden:

> Input: 52682
>
> Output: Verdadero
>
> Input: 53819
>
> Output: Falso

Lo mismo si los números 7 y 4 se encuentran dentro del número (No en los bordes):

> Input: 147419638
>
> Output: Verdadero
>
> Input: 25481548
>
> Output: Falso

Probé el siguiente código con el que logré leer los dos primero caracteres, pero no logro hacer para que lea los de en medio o los de al final sin tener que restringir la cantidad de caracteres que el usuario tenga que ingresar:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a[20];
    
    cin>>a;
    
    if (a[0] == '3' && a[1] == '7')
    {
        cout<<"Verdadero"<<endl;
    } else
    {
        cout<<"Falso"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Por qué no intentas pasar el número a texto y hacer una búsqueda de texto?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    auto numero = std::to_string(147419638);
    auto busqueda = std::to_string(47);
    auto posicion = numero.find(busqueda);

    switch (posicion)
    {
        case 0:
            std::cout << busqueda << " se encuentra al principio de " << numero;
            break;

        case std::string::npos:
            std::cout << "No se encuentra " << busqueda << " en " << numero;
            break;

        default:
            if (posicion == (numero.length() - busqueda.length()))
                std::cout << busqueda << " se encuentra al final de " << numero;
            else
                std::cout << numero << " contiene " << busqueda;
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como ya te han respondido acerca de cómo resolverlo con cadenas de caracteres, yo te explico como resolverlo gestionando únicamente números.

Para hacerlo jugando con números, el logaritmo en base 10 es un gran aliado. La gracia de este logaritmo es que permite calcular el número de dígitos de un número:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int numero;
  std::cin >> numero;

  std::cout << "El numero " << numero
            << " tiene " << static_cast<int>(std::log10(numero))+1
            << " digitos\n";
}
```

Esto lo puedes usar para extraer los dígitos iniciales con cierta facilidad. Para ello, sabiendo el número de dígitos a filtrar, basta con calcular la potencia en base 10 correspondiente y hacer una división:

```
numero: 371234
digitos: 6

necesito quedarme con los dos primeros, luego
digitos = digitos - 2 -> digitos = 4

divisor = 10^digitos = 10000
numero / divisor = 37 <<--- Lo que estamos buscando
```

Para quedarte con los dos últimos basta con calcular el resto de 100

```
numero: 1234582
numero / 100 = 12345
numero % 100 = 82 <<--- Lo que estamos buscando
```

Y, finalmente, para saber si el número tiene los dígitos 3 y 7 hay que descartar los dos extremos... el último dígito es facil de descartar porque basta con dividir el número entre 10. Para recorrer el número seguimos dividiendo entre 10 y nos quedamos con el resto, vigilando que el número sea mayor o igual a 10 para evitar procesar el dígito más significativo:

```
numero: 147419638
numero / 10 = 14741963 <<--- Digito menos significativo fuera
numero % 10 = 3 <<--- El numero tiene un tres

numero / 10 = 1474196
numero % 10 = 6

numero / 10 = 147419
numero % 10 = 9

numero / 10 = 14741
numero % 10 = 1

numero / 10 = 1474
numero % 10 = 4

numero / 10 = 147
numero % 10 = 7 <<--- El numero tiene un siete

numero / 10 = 14
numero % 10 = 4

numero / 10 = 1 <<--- Menor de 10, paramos para ignorar el digito más significativo
```

Dicho con código:

```
int digitos = static_cast<int>(std::log10(numero))+1;
int divisor = std::pow(10,digitos-2);
int primerosDigitos = numero / divisor;

bool cumple = ( primerosDigitos == 37 ); // Comprobamos si numero = 37XXXXX

int ultimosDigitos = numero % 100;
cumple |= ( ultimosDigitos == 82 ); // Comprobamos si numero = XXXX82

// Comprobamos si el numero tiene 3 y 7 y no estan en los extremos
bool tiene3 = false;
bool tiene7 = false;
while( numero>= 10 )
{
  numero/= 10;
  int digito = numero% 10;
  tiene3 |= (digito == 3);
  tiene7 |= (digito == 7);
}

cumple |= (tiene3 && tiene7);
std::cout << (cumple ? " Verdadero\n" : " Falso\n");
```